# Add/delete wireless networks from c#

Tags: c#, .net, windows-vista, wireless

It there a way I can access the list of stored wireless connections in C# (Window Vista)

I mean the list found in: "Control Panel" -> "Network and Sharing Center" -> "Manage Wireless Networks"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do some of this using [Managed Wifi](http://managedwifi.codeplex.com/), which wraps the [Native Wifi API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms706274%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

```
 NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
    .Where(x=>x.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211)
```